# emit events from one flow to another in coroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

So the idea is I have two flows one is a producer and another one is consumer how can I connect these two?

this is the RX equivalent of what I'm trying to do:

```
val producer = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
val consumer = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
producer.subscribe(consumer)
```

so far I have come with this implementation, but the problem is I need to have a defined scope, but sometimes I don't have a scope and I just simply want to connect these two together

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectIn(
    lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope,
    flow: MutableSharedFlow<T>
) = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
     collect(flow)
}
```

Comment: any update on this topic ?

Comment: The last time that I checked kotlin teams wanted to think about this feature but didn't check it recently

Comment: Hi!) Could you please elaborate, why do you want to do that? What use case?
I was thinking about mapping, but I am not sure if that's what you want to do (: